# How do I unlock an Oracle user's account from Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, system-administration

I'm trying to figure out why my application is unable to unlock a user's Oracle account successfully. Here's a snippet from my code:

```
OracleDataSource ods = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "sys");
props.put("password", "sys");
props.put("internal_logon", "sysdba");

ods.setConnectionProperties(props);
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:TEST_DB");

Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("ALTER USER SCOTT ACCOUNT UNLOCK");
stmt.close();
```

At no point does it raise an `SQLException` or report any problems, but the user's account doesn't actually get unlocked. Am I missing something obvious here or is there some cunning way of getting this to work?

Comment: What is the database version? Did you try the command in SQL Plus?

Comment: Oracle 10g, statement works perfectly in SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be very nervous about having an application connect as sysdba like this.

I would prefer to have a privileged user with permission to ALTER USER, remove the CREATE SESSION privilege from it, and have this schema contain an account_unlock pl/sql procedure for which execute privilege is granted to the user that your application connects with. ALTER USER is powerful stuff, and you probably want to restrict the attributes and even the individual users that your application can alter.

And that might also solve this problem.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, unfortunately I have a specific requirement which necessitates this approach. The application is intended as a simple support tool and will only ever be able to lock/unlock a user account and change a user's password.

Comment: I've changed the application to use a priviledged user rather than connecting as sysdba as you suggested, I figured out a different way to meet the other requirements that necessitated using sysdba. Whilst I can't explain why it didn't work before, it does now. Ta muchly!

Answer (score 1):

try using executeUpdate rather than just execute. e.g.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("ALTER USER SCOTT ACCOUNT UNLOCK")
```

Comment: I thought you might have been on to something here, but it makes no difference...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "commit" issue since this statement does not need a commit. Things to consider:

Does the statement unlock the account when you run it in SQLPLUS? 
Are you logging onto the correct database from java?
Is there some process trying to logon into the account whith the wrong credentials resulting in a locked account?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The statement works perfectly in SQL*Plus, I have checked the connection details for the database dozens of time and it is definitely the correct database and there are no other processes that could make this change other than the one I'm trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to see if this resolves the issue:

stmt.execute("BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER SCOTT ACCOUNT UNLOCK';  END;");

Comment: Sadly not. It runs, but doesn't affect the account status change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set *'autocommit'* property to *'true'* for your jdbc connection. May be it's just set to *'false'* by default and your sql is not committed.

Comment: a commit is not required for an ALTER USER

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that your code should work - I just did a quick test of it and the target account was unlocked.  Two questions come to mind:

- How are you determining the account
  is still locked?  Are you using
  *SELECT username, account_status FROM DBA_USERS*?
- Is there an Oracle profile in place  that locks the account for failed logon attempts?  Perhaps there is 
  another process trying and failing to connect with an incorrect password   that is re-locking the account.

Sorry to ask such basic questions, but again, your code does work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are running into a case-sensitivity issue with Oracle 11?

Answer (score 0):

It would be safer doing it through a callable statement which executes dynamic sql inside a package. That way you grant execute on a package eliminating the possibility of a SQL injection attack